# Simple Shell Script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a simple shell script .
The script goes to a folder, loops through every file, and reads every line in each file and prints them.

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
cd "My Directory Goes Here"

for myFile in `ls`
for line in `cat $myFile`;
    do   
    echo "$line"   
    done 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `do` for the outer loop and you're better off using `$()` instead of backticks (easier to read, easier to nest, and it should be understood by any modern `/bin/sh`). Also, you don't need to call `ls` to get a list of files in the current directory, you can just use `*`:

```
# If you're trying to echo $myFile line by line and your lines
# may have embedded whitespace, then you'll want to change the
# input-field-separator to keep $(cat $myFile) for tokenizing
# the file on whitespace. If your files don't have whitespace
# in the lines, then you don't need to change IFS like this.
IFS=''

cd "My Directory Goes Here"
for myFile in *; do
    for line in $(cat $myFile); do
        echo $line
    done
done
```

The above will miss files like `.dotfile` but you can use `find` if you need those too:

```
for myFile in $(find . -type f -maxdepth 1); do
    # As above
```

And if you have to deal with files that contain spaces in their names then you're better off using something other than the shell such as Perl, Ruby, or Python.

Comment: This is the selected answer, but does this work? `1.` First answer  doesn't take care of the separator, it spits out the contents word by word(separated by space) than line by line `2.` find command throws error saying options should come before arguments. `3.` using cat the way it is used is cat abuse. :)

Comment: @Lobo: `1.` Depends on the format of the files, there is some ambiguity here though and setting `IFS=''` will fix that so I'll add an update. `2.` The `find` command works just fine, what sort of overly strict bondage and discipline `find` are you using? `3.` That isn't really cat abuse, cat abuse is `cat stuff | mangler` rather than the non-abusive `mangler < stuff`, I like cats too much to abuse them :)

Answer (score 1):

Use find command and pipe the result to cat. Use xargs to avoid `Argument list too long` failure.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

You can replace your entire second for loop with just `cat $myFile` instead of taking each line and printing it.

**update**

```
oldIFS='$IFS'
IFS='
'
for line in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat`; do
        echo $line
done
IFS='$oldIFS'
```

if you want to do it without changing the IFS(Internal Field Separator) -

```
for file in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f `; do
    while read line; do
        echo $line
    done<$file
done
```

Comment: thanks but I need to use the result of every line that i read, is it possible to assign each line of text to a variable and use it somehow?